# What is the difference between MaxPool and MaxPooling layers in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I just started working with [keras](/questions/tagged/keras) and noticed that there are two layers with very similar names for max-pooling: `MaxPool` and `MaxPooling`. I was surprised that I couldn't find the difference between these two on Google; so I am wondering what the difference is between the two if any.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**They are the same**... You can test it on your own

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *

# create dummy data
X = np.random.uniform(0,1, (32,5,3)).astype(np.float32)

pool1 = MaxPool1D()(X)
pool2 = MaxPooling1D()(X)

tf.reduce_all(pool1 == pool2) # True
```

I used 1D max-pooling but the same is valid for all the pooling operations (2D, 3D, avg, global pooling)

Answer (score 28):

They are basically the same thing (i.e. aliases of each other). For future readers who might want to know how this could be determined: go to the documentation page of the layer (you can use the list [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers)) and click on "View aliases". This is then accompanied by a blue plus sign (+).

For example, if you go to `MaxPool2D` [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/MaxPool2D) and do this, you will find `MaxPooling2D` in the list of aliases of this layer as follow:

[image: MaxPool aliases in Keras]

Answer (score 2):

Ther are the same. The library is soo many times updated that's why there are some functions with different names but with the same tasks. you can use any of them.