# Tensorflow difference between *pool2D and *pooling2D

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am learning this [TensorFlow-2.x-Tutorials](https://github.com/dragen1860/TensorFlow-2.x-Tutorials/tree/master/01-TF2.0-Overview) where it use `layers.MaxPooling2D`. The autocompletion also hint `layers.MaxPool2D`, so I search for the difference between them.

Refer to this [api_docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/), I find their entire name `tf.compat.v1.layers.MaxPooling2D` and `tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D`, which have almost same arguments, can I just consider `layers.MaxPooling2D` = `layers.MaxPool2D`, but the former is to tf1.x, the latter is to tf2.x?

What's more, I also find `tf.keras.layers.GlobalMaxPool1D`(Global max pooling operation for 1D temporal data) and `tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D`(Global average pooling operation for temporal data), these two have exact the same arguments, why is the syntax of function name different?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between MaxPool and MaxPooling layers in Keras?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63006575/what-is-the-difference-between-maxpool-and-maxpooling-layers-in-keras)

Answer (score 0):

I'm only going to answer your second question because someone found a duplicate for your first one.

`MaxPooling2D` takes the maximum value from a 2D array. Take for example this input:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.random.uniform(minval=0, maxval=10, dtype=tf.int32, shape=(3, 3, 3), seed=42)
```

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 3, 3), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[[2, 4, 3],
        [9, 1, 8],
        [8, 3, 5]],
       [[6, 6, 9],
        [9, 6, 1],
        [7, 5, 2]],
       [[2, 0, 8],
        [1, 6, 1],
        [2, 3, 9]]])>
```

`MaxPooling2D` will take the average value of all of these three elements:

```
gmp = tf.keras.layers.GlobalMaxPooling2D()

gmp(x[..., None])
```

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 1), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[9],
       [9],
       [9]])>
```

There's a 9 in every elements so the operation returns a 9 for all three. For `GlobalAveragePooling2D`, it's the exact same thing but with averaging.

```
gap = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()

gap(x[..., None])
```

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 1), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[3],
       [6],
       [5]])>
```

Comment: I understand that the key difference is 'Max' and 'Average', but I am curious about the syntax of function name, 'Pooling' and 'Pool'. I realized `tf.keras.layers.GlobalMaxPooling2D` has 4 alias: `tf.compat.v1.keras.layers.GlobalMaxPool2D`, `tf.compat.v1.keras.layers.GlobalMaxPooling2D`, `tf.compat.v2.keras.layers.GlobalMaxPool2D`, `tf.compat.v2.keras.layers.GlobalMaxPooling2D`, kind of redundant and inconsistent.

Comment: `v1.compat` is a way to use Tensorflow 1.X code via Tensorflow 2.X. So you don't have to change your code, only your import statements and then you can run old Tensorflow code in the newer Tensorflow versions. If you're using Keras the changes will be minimal, if any, so it explains why all of these are seem identical (except for the changes under the hood). Source: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate. your other question was answered already so I didn't mention it.